# Insert before last child element of a div

Tags: javascript, html

so basically I'm trying to reproduce some kind of Trello, and what I'm trying to do, is to create (or clone) an existing div, and insert it before the button. Yes I know, there's a method called ".insertBefore()" but I actually tried, it works... But halfway.

[This is how the div should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85YQp.png)

[Blocks are disposed in this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmVto.png), and as I said, what I am trying to do is when I click on the "Add Category button" It clones the div and inserts it before the button.
Nothing difficult I know I know. I actually managed to achieve this, but halfway : It works. But only once.

I looked what's happening in the inspector and I noticed, that everytime I click on "Add Category", the div I just cloned, is actually replaced by the div itself. So I can only add it once, not more.

There is my code :

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var board = document.querySelector('#board');
    var model = document.querySelectorAll('#model');

    //creating the block, didn't use .cloneNode()
    var newTask = document.createElement('div');
    newTask.className='newTask';
    newTask.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
    newTask.querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'New Task';
    newTask.appendChild(document.createElement('i'));
    newTask.querySelector('i').className = 'fa fa-plus';
    var newCategory = document.createElement('div');
    newCategory.className = 'category';
    newCategory.appendChild(newTask);
    /* Look like this :
     * <div class="category">
     *      <div class="newTask">
     *          <p>New Task</p>
     *          <i class="fa fa-plus">
     *      </div>
     * </div>
     */

    var addCategory = document.querySelector('#addCategory');
    addCategory.onclick = function() {
        board.insertBefore(newCategory, addCategory);
    };
};
```

```html
<div id="board">
    <div class="category hidden" id="model">
        <div class="newTask">
            <p>New task</p>
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <div class="newTask">
            <p>New task</p>
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="task">
            <h3>Task title</h3>
            <p>This is the description of what we have to do</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category" id="addCategory">
        <h3>Add a category</h3>
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>            
    </div>
</div>
```

So this is what's happening : https://i.neilrichter.com/c7kd3.gif (File too large sorry)

How would you solve this ? I forgot to mention it, but I'm not allowed to use jQuery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only creating the div once (when the window loads) and then inserting that same div every time the onclick handler runs.

You need to create a new div each time the onclick handler runs:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var board = document.querySelector('#board');
    var model = document.querySelectorAll('#model');

    var addCategory = document.querySelector('#addCategory');
    addCategory.onclick = function() {
        var newTask = document.createElement('div');
        newTask.className='newTask';
        newTask.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
        newTask.querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'New Task';
        newTask.appendChild(document.createElement('i'));
        newTask.querySelector('i').className = 'fa fa-plus';
        var newCategory = document.createElement('div');
        newCategory.className = 'category';
        newCategory.appendChild(newTask);

        board.insertBefore(newCategory, addCategory);
    };
};
```

```html
<div id="board">
    <div class="category hidden" id="model">
        <div class="newTask">
            <p>New task</p>
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <div class="newTask">
            <p>New task</p>
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="task">
            <h3>Task title</h3>
            <p>This is the description of what we have to do</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category" id="addCategory">
        <h3>Add a category</h3>
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>            
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed, I found the solution while you were writing I guess : I put the construction of the block in a function, function that I call as the first argument in the method insertBefore!